# OO & Application Objects

Tags: oop

In OO apps, it's common to have an Application class which holds your top-level managers or whatever. This makes it hard to avoid having a `theApp` global object, or using a Singleton or something.

Does it matter? Should we seek to make this as OO as possible, or accept that OO principles break down sometimes?

Answer (score 2):

> Does it matter? Should we seek to make this as OO as possible, or accept that OO principles break down sometimes?

Sometimes OO theory meets the real world, and you should strive to make things work for your customers first and foremost. A singleton here or there is not a problem for your customer, or for maintainability.

OOP is mainly there to make code easier to maintain, reuse and understand. As long as those goals are met, there is no need to refactor for purity reasons only.

Answer (score 1):

Having a global `theApp` object singleton doesn't *necessarily* violate OO principles, so long as data tied to it is properly encapsulated and whatnot.

There's also the situation that few OS's actually have an OO core, meaning that the Application Loader isn't Object Oriented to begin with.

In any case, absolutism on this point is dangerous; some programming languages have an (IMO) overly zealous approach to the whole thing, dictating every function be a method or the like, even when this doesn't make a lick of sense. (`System.Math.sin(x)`, anyone?)

The most effective approach is usually mixing the two methodologies, using functions for functions, and methods for methods; and by extension, using Singletons for things that truly are singular; such as the application object or interfaces to *some* system services.

**Edit:** On `System.Math.sin(x)`, it should be made clear that sin(x) is a function in quite literally every sense of the word, and putting it as a method on a singleton is wildly irresponsible, or at least a bit silly. In the comments a case could exist where another class wanted to use the name sin() for a method, but as methods and functions reside in separate namespaces in any case, this really isn't relevant.

Comment: I tend to treat `System.Math` more as a namespace containing functions.

Answer (score 0):

I think the goal should be to design as well as possible. I don't want to have a mindset of seek "badges" or stamps of approval, so I'm not interested being as as "OO as possible", rather I seek to make concious trades-off. We favour concepts such as de-coupling and single-responsibility not because it's OO or because we can claim to be using a Design Pattern, but because we increase the ease of development, maintainability, testability and so on. We also favour simplicity because that too increases mainatainability and testability - the "You ain't gonna need it" principle leads us sometimes to leave things a little mre tightly coupled because we don't need flexibility right now.

So, to consider you example, there may well be a singleton in the sense that yes, there is only one of something (a thread pool or some such) but does the code using it need to know that it's a singleton? With a bit of care, use of factories or injection we can limit the knowledge of the n-gleton-ness.

Answer (score 0):

There is no breakdown of OO by having a "theApp" object.

Comment: It's not a break down of OO, but it breaks what many consider good OO _design_, or at least it very easily can.

Comment: No. I'd have to respectfully disagree. Your application being represented by some sort of "theApp" object is not bad design whatsoever. Not even in the slightest. Now, what you DO with "theApp" object might be bad -- just like you can abuse anything.